# How to extract into lists all the values for each key in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have some code which loops through a nested dictionary and extracts the nested values into lists but thought there has to be a more pythonic way of doing it.

**Code**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    master_dict = {"1": {"1": 11, "2":22, "3": 33},
                   "2": {"1": 15, "2":23, "3": 31}}

    #print(master_dict, '\n')
    ones = []
    twenties = []
    thirties = []
    for k, v in master_dict.items():
        #print(k, " : ", v)
        ones.append(v["1"])
        twenties.append(v["2"])
        thirties.append(v["3"])

    print("ones : ", ones)
    print("twenties : ", twenties)
    print("thirties : ", thirties)
```

**Returns**

```
ones :  [11, 15]
twenties :  [22, 23]
thirties :  [33, 31]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If looks like you don't care about the keys of the master dict, but only the nested dictionaries. The following code will create a new, single dict that has all keys from your sub-dictionaries and all values collected in a list.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict as dd
>>> outcome = dd(list)
>>> for d in master_dict.values():
...   for k, v in d.items():
...     outcome[k].append(v)
...
>>> outcome
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'1': [11, 15], '2': [22, 23], '3': [33, 31]})
```

The `outcome` object behaves just like a dict, but if you prefer, you can also convert it to a regular dict:

```
>>> dict(outcome)
{'1': [11, 15], '2': [22, 23], '3': [33, 31]}
```

Accessing your `ones`, `twenties` and `thirties` is now as simple as:

```
>>> outcome["1"]
[11, 15]
>>> outcome["2"]
[22, 23]
>>> outcome["3"]
[33, 31]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use pandas to do that:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
master_dict = {"a": {"1": 11, "2":22, "3": 33},
                   "b": {"1": 15, "2":23, "3": 31}}
df = DataFrame(data=master_dict)
print(np.array(df[0:1]).tolist()[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the recursive function for this.

```
def extract_values(data):
    values_by_key = {}
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            sub_values = extract_values(value)
            for sub_key, sub_value in sub_values.items():
                if sub_key in values_by_key:
                    values_by_key[sub_key].extend(sub_value)
                else:
                    values_by_key[sub_key] = sub_value
        else:
            if key in values_by_key:
                values_by_key[key].append(value)
            else:
                values_by_key[key] = [value]
    return values_by_key
```